# Flexbox not overflowing parent position: absolute

Tags: css

How to stop a flexbox (dialogbox/modal) to overflow the parent element which is `position: absolute` ?

Right now if you resize the window `.modal` will overflow the parent `#modal` and the window. I want to add overflow to the body element in the modal

https://jsfiddle.net/fdo8an4c/

```
<div id="modal">
  <div class="modal">
    <div>
      body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
    </div>
    <div class="modal-actions">
      actions
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

#modal{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    display:flex;
    background:red;
}

.modal{
    margin:auto;
    padding:20px;
    width:200px;
    min-height:150px;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:column wrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:stretch;
    background:#fff;
}

.modal-actions{
    padding-top:10px;
    text-align:right;
  background:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

1. Remove `min-height` and add `max-height: 100vh;` on `.modal`.
2. Add `max-height: calc(100vh - 80px)` (80px is the button + paddings + a little more space for the modal to breathe) and `overflow: auto` on the modal body (the first div I assume).

```
<div id="modal">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-body">
      body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
    </div>
    <div class="modal-actions">
      actions
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

#modal{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    display:flex;
    background:red;
}

.modal{
    margin:auto;
    padding:20px;
    width:200px;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:column wrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:stretch;
    background:#fff;
    max-height: 100vh;
}

.modal-body {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    overflow: auto;
}

.modal-actions{
    padding-top:10px;
    text-align:right;
  background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: I can't make it work? Could you show an example?

Comment: Sure, I've added it to the answer.